# Is there any advantage to creating a subdomain for my LDAP server?

Tags: ldap, openldap, best-practices

Having just started using OpenLDAP to authenticate users across web apps, I'm intrigued by a pattern I'm seeing in the documentation: Most install/config guides seem to (implicitly) recommend running the ldap server on `ldap.whatever.org`.

As I installed ldap on my VPS, I just thought it'd be simpler to access it all through `whatever.org`.

Is there any benefit of either approach? Or is it just assumed that the ldap software will run on it's own machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you ever wish to separate services into different boxes, you'll want to use subdomains.

Think about what happens when you run LDAP and a web server on mydomain.com and later on you decide to move the web server somewhere else, but LDAP stays in the same box.

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice that services accross a domain are named as follow

> protocol.domain.tld

But, that's just good practice. If you prefer to name it mygrandmotherlovesmakingcrepes.caribou.org, and this name resolves to your LDAP server, feel free to do so :)

In fact, if you ldap and your webapps are running locally, you might as well connect to it using ldap://127.0.0.1.